# Modular arithmatic in Rabin-karp algorithm

Tags: string-matching, modular-arithmetic, clrs, rabin-karp

[image]

I am studying Rabin-karp algotithm for string matching from CLRS in which modular arithmetic is used for hashing which i haven't studied so what I don't understand is that how does (7 – 3·3)·10 + 2 (mod 13) evaluate to 8 (mod 13)

Answer (score 0):

(7 – 3·3)·10 + 2 (mod 13) evaluate to 8 (mod 13)

Because 7 - 9 = 11, not -2.